# Python3 Replace "/" With "\"

Tags: qgis-3, python-3, string

I want to import several spatial csv files (points) into QGIS.
The path to the folder, where the csv files are located is stored in the variable "Folder_Path".
The file names are stored in a list.

It seems to me, that the only way to create a memory layer in this case is with a uri. But the uri in the syntax of QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'Test', 'delimitedtext') has instead of a forward slash "/" a backward slash "\".
Replacing the forward slash with a backward slash doesn't work with my code:

```py
Folder_Path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(caption="Pick Folder 'Import_QGIS'.")

#Folder_Path for uri
Folder_Path_uri = Folder_Path.replace("/", "\")
```

Result is SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

How can I let Python know, that the "\" is just a character and not an escape?
Or is there a better way to go about adding csv files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\` is hiding the closing `"` so you need to use `\\` - but python shouldn't care about the slashes in the path.

Comment: Damn, you're fast :)

Comment: also worth checking: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html